# jquery ajax request not working on remote server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is the first time i am trying to upload my work on a webhost from localhost.I have an ajax request to submit a form and get somre response from the server.But the **success method** is **not** triggering ,instead **error method** is triggering.Though it is working fine on `localhost` but for some reason it is not working on `remote server`.I think it is the url in the ajax request which is not getting the file though it is fine on localhost.What might be the reason for this and how i can fix this?

i checked all the sql related with this ajax request.ALl working fine .

***my domain name is :ezphp.tk***

***my question is is attaching the file location in the url is enough like i did or i had to treat it with something like http://mydomain/filepath.....***

ajax submission :

```
 $.ajax('../includes/verifyanswer.php',{
        data:{

            'answer_body': CKEDITOR.instances.content.getData(),
            'userpost_post_id': <?php echo $postid;?>,
            'users_user_id': <?php echo $userdata->user_id; ?>
             },
        type:"POST",
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(response){




           alert('bal');
             var obj=response;
           alert(obj[0].answer_body);
              $('#mainanswer').hide();
              $('#answerform').hide();
              $('#answerthisquestion').show();
              var str="<div class='styleanswer' >"+obj[0]['answer_body']+"</div><div class='customcmntholder'></div><span id='customcomment' class='cmnt' onclick='letmecomment(event);'>Add a Comment...</span><form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' method='post'  name='cmntform'> <textarea  data-id="+obj[0]['answer_id']+" class='customcmntform' placeholder=' add a comment......' ></textarea></form><hr>";

              $('#answerwrapper').append(str);
                $('#answerwrapper pre code').each(function(i, block) {
                   hljs.highlightBlock(block);
              });

        },
        error:function(response){
              alert('there are some errors');
           }
    });
```

verifyanswer.php file is :

```
 require_once '../core/init.php';
   $answer=$_POST['answer_body'];

   $post_id=$_POST['userpost_post_id'];
   $answerer=$_POST['users_user_id'];
   if(isset($answer,$post_id,$answerer)){
     if(!empty($answer) && !empty($post_id) && !empty($answerer)){
           $db=DB::getInstance();
           $result=$db->post_and_fetch("CALL login.post_and_fetch_ans(?,?,?)",array($answer,$post_id,$answerer))->result();
                echo json_encode($result);

       }
   }
```

Comment: Did you check your ajax request url in headers?

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: Your're using relative path in ajax request url, once try with a static remote url. There may be issue with ajax url.

Comment: can you explain it in plain words :(.. going over my head

Comment: Replace you ajax request url with this `$.ajax('http://mydomain/includes/verifyanswer.php',{ ... });`

Comment: printing error still :(

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is ajax cross domain.
You can set in php file by code:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
```

Or reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain) to resolve it

Comment: but all my files are on same server

Comment: what is your solution.i didn't understand it.how it relates to my problem?

Comment: So, you can use `try catch ` to catch error in php file. If you dont know error, you cant fix it.

Answer (score 0):

On your first php page when you call the ajax function try either of these two method:

```
 <!-- This is your form -->
 <form name="yourForm" id="yourForm" method="post" action="http://yourdomain.com/includes/verifyanswer.php" novalidate >
 <input type="submit"  />
 </form>
```

This is method to call ajax after form submission:

```
$('#yourForm').on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            dataType: "json", 
            data:formData,
            processData: false,
            success:function(data){
            alert(data);

            },
            error: function(data){
                alert('there are some errors');
            }
        });

    }));
```

This is to call ajax through your custom function:

```
function testFunction()
{
    var yourparam1 = "abc";
    var yourparam2 = "123";

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://yourdomain.com/includes/verifyanswer.php",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
                   param1 : yourparam1,
                   param2 : yourparam1
                },
          success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
          },
           error: function(data){
                alert('there are some errors');
           }
        });

}
```

Add this line on top of your php page from where you are getting ajax json data:

```
// PHP headers (at the top)
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json");

$output = "Hello world";
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: both of them are php page..which php page are you talking about?

Comment: Also make sure you use full path in ajax call e.g. http://yourdomain.com/includes/verifyanswer.php

Answer (score 0):

first, you needs to check what exactly error you get from your ajax request, is this caused by cors or something else

change your jquery error function like below:

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
  alert(err.Message);
}
```

if you using shared hosting for your website, then you need to allow your web is can access from all origin using this, there are several ways to allow cross origin:

1. in your resuested php file: added header to allow your acces origin  using this :  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
2. or you can config all your web using .httaccess

for more info about cors enable, you can visit here [enable-cors.org](http://enable-cors.org/server.html)